# Equivalent of FOUND_ROWS() function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, paging

I am doing some paging in my application, returning 20 rows from the database at a time using PostgreSQL's standard OFFSET and LIMIT keywords.  For instance, to get page 1 page:

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY stuff OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20
```

It is a requirement of the application that we also show to the user the total number of records.  So, obviously, I can get the total by issuing a separate query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition
```

But if there are a large number of rows then this is not an optimal solution.  I notice that MySQL has a very useful function called FOUND_ROWS() that does exactly what I am looking for:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function%5Ffound-rows

Is there an equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

PostgreSQL has had [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) for a while now which can be used to do many things including counting rows before LIMIT is applied.

Based on the example above:

```
SELECT stuff,
       count(*) OVER() AS total_count
FROM table
WHERE condition
ORDER BY stuff OFFSET 40 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: will `count(*) OVER() AS total_count` be executed for every row? e.g. if we have 20 rows, does it mean it will be calculated 20 times, or only once?

Comment: It will be executed only once.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the best solution for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent.
look at

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2007-07/msg00108.php

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    n_live_tup     
FROM
    pg_stat_user_tables     
WHERE 
    relname = 'table_Name';
```