# SQL requests for HTTP range response header

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, http

I'm currently implementing a pagination based on HTTP range header on a Ruby on Rails application, and I'm wondering about SQL performances.

Unlike the traditional `page` and `per_page` query string params, the [range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) design allow the server to inform the client about the number of total result in the database. For example:

```
Content-Range: 0-4/123
```

Informing that:

- the collection contains 5 records,
- the database contains 123 records.

But I'm wondering about performances. If we use this pagination design, then we have to do 2 SQL requests:

- 1 request to get the 5 items,
- 1 request to get the total number of items.

Am I right? Or is there a way to find both informations without a downside?

Comment: You could probably hack away at a SQL query which selects both the items and the count but will it be significantly faster than two queries?

Comment: You mean, with a sub-query? If you have an example, please show me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22353886/2115135

Comment: `result = User.select('users.*, COUNT(id) OVER() AS tc').limit(5)`. `result.first.tc ==  User.count # true` However this is Postgres spefic.

Comment: And it will mess up the normal count method and other things for the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use [`FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
```

Then to get the total number of rows if there weren't a limit:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

You don't save tons, but you can save some. And still, [your mileage may vary](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/).